# Which is faster way to find a child element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Let's say I need to work with several different child elements within a parent container, then which is the faster/efficient way?

```
var par = $("#parent");
$("child1",par).doSomething();

OR

par.find("child1").doSomething();

OR

par.children("child1").doSomething();
```

Comment: Try using http://jsperf.com/.

Comment: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization

Comment: IDs must be unique on context page, so using as selector `#child1` alone will always be the fastest way. Just be aware than in you case, the fastest way would be: `$(document.getElementById('child1'))` But ya, check @undefined's link

Comment: I'd use `$('#parent child1')`

Comment: @Doorknob which will return an empty object, it won't work!

Comment: @A.Wolff Why do you think that?

Comment: @Doorknob OP edited is question making my last comment no more relevant. Sorry!

Comment: OP please don't edit question, you make answers no more relevant and looks like you don't know what you are asking...  It was '#child1' now it is 'child1', well, have you really any element of type 'child1'? Really, your question is pointless!

Comment: I edited only once. Anyway Doorknob's way won't work, because since I am trying to work with multiple children inside a parent object, the first optimization is to keep a reference to parent, not call it repeatedly.

Comment: based on the suggestion of @BYossarian http://jsperf.com/childresponse

Comment: Hmm...it seems as per that, `find` is faster than `children`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you comparing between [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/),Then fastest would be

```
par.children("child1").doSomething();
```

Because children only looks for immediate children node of the element whereas `find` looks for entire DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the id selector directly as @Arun opted. And if you you have any class selector present inside the any element with the id, you could use like this,

```
$("#id-selector").find(".class-selector");
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest between [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) would be

```
par.children("child1").doSomething();
```

Because `children` as name suggests looks for children node's only whereas `find` looks all the way to descendant's (grandchildren's and so on).